# TextBoxFor tabindex not rendering at all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tabindex, mvcrazor

I need to reorder the TAB key navigation and I am growing increasingly frustrated with how difficult it is to use tabindex. I need to modify the following to include tabindex

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.project_name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.project_name, new { @data_bind = "value: woheader_projectName" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.project_name)
```

I  tried

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.project_name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.project_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { tabindex = "8" } }, new { @data_bind = "value: woheader_projectName" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.project_name)
```

As well as few other variations and I am getting errors.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine all html attributes in the 2nd parameter

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.project_name, new { tabindex = "8", data_bind = "value: woheader_projectName" })
```